# QUDP socket how to check if data not recived for specific time in qt

Tags: qt, sockets, timer, udp

I Appling QUDP socket in qt .. I was able to send and receive data however I am thinking on how to check if data is data not received for specific time for example 5 second which mean there is an issue with communication so I can send a command to notify the user ..

any suggestion ?!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html)...

```
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
timer.setInterval(5000);
QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,
                 []()
                 {

                   /*
                    * Your notification code goes here.
                    */
                 });
```

Then, every time you receive data via the `QUdpSocket` just restart the timer...

```
timer.stop();
timer.start();
```

Of course, how effective/useful this is depends to a large extent on the rate at which you're receiving data.